# Creating and pushing transactions while preserving IP privacy

Tags: transactions

What is the simplest way to generate a signed transaction without compromising your IP address? MEW for one either doesn't work over TOR at all, or when it does it makes the signed transaction impossible to copy, and in that case the send transaction button doesn't work either. (Is that intentional or just bugs?)

Is there a way to make MEW work properly under TOR? Or perhaps there is some other tool that I am not aware of yet? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is any IP address associated with the transactions.

It's possible that someone could determine the node where the transaction was originally created, but it isn't likely they could determine the IP that submitted the transaction to that node unless the node keeps detailed logs and made those logs available to the public or was hacked.

TL;DR make yourself a geth node that isn't on your own IP, and submit your transactions to that.

Comment: How would one go about running a full node over an IP address that is not theirs?

Comment: Any cloud-based hosting service can do this for you.  You rent a VM from them, it uses their IP rather than yours.  If you're trying to hide from the NSA that isn't going to help you at all, but if you just want general privacy from the public, the only people that will reasonably know your identity is the cloud service.